# problemas con cordova camara ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic, cordova, ng-cordova

amigos estoy tratando de usar la camara con ionic 
este es el controlador para la camara 
pero al ejecutarlo me sale el error:
ionic.bundle.js:20434 ReferenceError: Camera is not defined
y he removido las platamformas los plugin y nada. que puedo hacer

```
.controller('camaraCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaCamera) {
    var options = {
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG
    }
    $scope.PictureUrl = 'http://placehold.it/150x150';
    $scope.TomarFoto = function() {
        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options)
            .then(function(data) {
                console.log('camara' + angular.toJson(data));
                 $scope.PictureUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + data;
            }, function(error) {
                console.log('camara err' + angular.toJson(data));
            })
    }
})
```

Comment: ¿Cuándo se llama a este código?¿estás seguro que se ha cargado el plugin de la cámara?

Comment: Si has quitado las plataformas y los plugins no te puede funcionar, ya que la camara es un plugin. Agrega las plataformas y los plugins de nuevo y se debe resolver tu problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asegurate que tengas instalados los packages correctos, infiero que estas corriendo esto en web, instalalo en tu celular e pruebalo.

Con genymotion me dio algunos problemas, y corriendo en serve me marca ese mismo error, pero mejor correlo en tu celular para que funcione.

```
cordova run android
```